# Is there a way to get the length in minutes of a video file stored in Google Drive with GoogleApps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm making a script that makes a list of all my videos stored in Google Drive.
I know how to get name, link, description, size, creation date etc..
I'm wondering if ther's a way to also get the lenght of the video file.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot retrieve the duration of a video from Google Drive. you would need to upload the file to YouTube and use the YouTube class.

Comment: Could it? If you know something we don't, please enlighten.